# Como fazer formatação de Números no Excel programaticamente em C#

Tags: c#, microsoft-excel

Estou montando um relatório de Pedidos em C#, estou usando a biblioteca `Microsoft.Interop.Excel` e enfrento um problema:

É necessário incluir nesse relatório o número do Pedido e ao ser apresentado no Excel, ele vem em Formato Exponencial: `7,80005E+12`, sendo que o original seria: `78000496698755`.

Li na Web que colocando um Apostrofo antes do texto ele viria correto, o problema é que esse número é necessário para outras conversões dentro e fora do arquivo do programa e esse apostrofo está barrando algumas dessas conversões.

Minha pergunta é: Existe algum tipo de formatação que eu posso colocar para o conteudo vir corretamente, eu tentei o código abaixo, mas sem sucesso:

```
NumberFormat = "@";
```

Comment: dê uma olhada: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3879463/parse-a-number-from-exponential-notation

Comment: Quase isso Thiago, o número está ali, mas o Excel, por padrão o converte para Exponencial (sabe deus porquê), tentei usar isso aqui mas continua igual

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não entendi a pergunta completamente mas tente:

```
NumberFormat = "0";
```

Usando esse código é formatado a célula como números, no meu exemplo eu estava formatando como texto geral(onde eu caia no problema da Exponenciação).

Comment: Lucas, seguindo a analogia, se eu precisasse omitir algumas casas decimais, usaria o NumberFormat = "0.0"?

Comment: @GuilhermeGolfetto, neste caso use:  
NumberFormat = "0,0"  
Para verificar outros formatos, sugiro que dê uma olhada diretamente no excel. Pressionando ctrl+1 abrirá o menu de formatação de células. Escolha a opção "personalizado" ou "custom" dependendo do idioma. Lá você verá diversos formatos de número e o código que os representa.